# Under what circumstances would the _DELETE trigger get called? (_EVW)

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, versioning, delete, trigger

*Oracle 18c/10.7.1 geodatabase:*

When an FC is registered as versioned (with option to move edits to base), several triggers get automatically created:

- V000001_DELETE
- V000001_INSERT
- V000001_UPDATE

---

When I look at the _DELETE trigger, I see that it belongs to the versioned view:

```
INSTEAD OF DELETE
ON MAXIMO.TEST_FC_EVW  --<<--- versioned view
```

---

If I delete a feature from the feature class while using the default version, the trigger does **not** get called.

Question:

Under what circumstances would the _DELETE trigger get called?

Comment: When a DELETE is requested on the view (not the feature class).

Comment: @Vince I wasn't aware that users could edit/delete data through views in ArcObjects applications. Are the deletes on the versioned views done by users, or are they done by a backend process?

Comment: Versioned views are for use from SQL, not ArcObjects. The [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/overview-edit-versioned-data-with-sql.htm) describes their use case.

Answer (score 1):

The delete trigger would get called when deletion of the feature is done from a child version.
The deleted row would be stored in the delta D table created upon registering the FC as versioned for the feature class.